# how to require js file in a src file inside <script>?

Tags: javascript, require

I hope this is clear, I need to import a JS file in HTML file. So I'm using `src` attribute like this :

```html
<script src="my/js/file/1.js">
<!-- Some JS script here -->
</script>
```

But there is a thing... In my JS file, line 1, there is a `require("another/file.js")`... So I got an error in my browser console : `require is not defined`. How to solve it ?

#### EDIT

I'll try to be more clear :

I got 3 files, 1 HTML & 2 JS

The script tag above is in my html file.
In the src file, I need to import a 2nd JS file with `require("my/js/file/2.js"`
And it's working if i'm not using `src` attribute

But I got a error msg in console when I add src attribute

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-js-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined#answer-19059825

Comment: You can't both add a script with `src` _and_ have code inside the script tags.

Comment: @IMSoP Not really, or I'm missing smthg...
@War10ck It's not really about the 1st file, with my `<script src="path/to.js">`, I can get the 1st JS file, but this file also have a `require`, and this is the pb

Comment: @Andy Well, it's look like it's working, but even spliting it like this:
```html
<script type="module" src="file.js"></script>
<script>
<!-- my code here -->
</script>
```
I still have pb

Comment: @Devinfo_DH I don't see the difference between your question and this one: you want to require a second JS file from inside the first one; the linked duplicate discusses all the possible ways of doing that.

Comment: @IMSoP So I must have miss something, sorry. I'll read it again
Or maybe it's because it's not importing a js file into another one, but the `require` is working, but not when I'm using the 1st JS file in script tag

Comment: Maybe _I'm_ missing something.  What does `require("another/file.js")` mean _other than_ importing a JS file into another one? And where are you running it _other than_ in a script tag?

Comment: I'm using a JS class in my html file, and I need to import it. So I've to use `src` attribute.

But in this class, I also need to use module from another JS file, so there is a `require()` at line 1

The problem is the `require()` that trigger the error msg

Comment: @Devinfo_DH So, you have a JS file (the one you reference in the `src` attribute) and it needs to use another JS file (the one in the `require` line). That's exactly what the linked question is talking about. The error message is triggered because there is no function in standard JS called "require". What I don't understand is what you mean by "the require is working" - _when_ is that line working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require` is a built-in function provided by JS environments that support a couple of different kinds of modules, so how you load your JS file into a browser depends on what type of module system it is written to use.

The most likely cases are:

- It is is a AMD module (**very** unlikely in 2021) in which case you can probably load it with [RequireJS](https://requirejs.org/)
- It is a CommonJS module that depends on Node.js-specific APIs (in which case it can't run in a browser and to interact with it in a browser you would need to build it into a web service and make HTTP requests to it (e.g. via Ajax)). Some things that depend on Node.js-specific APIs include:

  - Making HTTP requests to sites which don't grant permission for browser JS to access them using CORS
  - Non-HTTP network requests (like direct access to a MySQL database)
  - Reading (or doing anything with) files from a file path expressed as a string (as opposed to reading files from a `<input type="file">`)
  - Spawning other processes
- It is a CommonJS module that doesn't depend on Node.js-specific APIs and you can convert it to run in a browser using a bundler tool such as [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/).

Find out which of those options it is **before** you start trying to implement one of these solutions (all of which will take some time and effort that you don't want to waste).

Reading the documentation for a module will usually tell you. If you get it from NPM and it doesn't mention being browser compatible then it is probably Node.js only.

Comment: I won't lie, it's a project made by people more experts than me, and I don't really know the different type of modules. I think it's a CommonJS module, but I'm not 100% sure and I can't say if it depends on Node.js-specific APIs

Comment: Try reading its documentation.

Comment: I'll read it when I'll be at home, for my own, thx ^^

Someone help me with my problem, I won't be able to say 100% of what we did in SO, but it's similar to your answer. So I'll mark your answer as correct.
I can't explain how we do without showing some private content, so I'm sry.

Answer (score -1):

This might be because `require()` is not part of the standard JavaScript API. Your code might be using Nodejs, which is where `require()` might be used. Also, for you to choose an `src` file, you might also want to include the `type` which is `<script type="text/javascript">`.